# Error when applying function to more n in r

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I wrote a function to simulate some patient data in date format (admission date, medication dates etc.)

```
    dates <- function(x){

  start_date <- as.Date(sample(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-31"), 1), 1))

  end_date <- as.Date(sample(seq(start_date, start_date + 20, 1), 1))

  ab_start <- as.Date(sample(seq(start_date, start_date + 3, 1), 1))

  ab_stop <- as.Date(sample(seq(ab_start, end_date, 1), 1))

  bc_date <- as.Date(sample(seq(start_date-1, start_date + 4, 1), 1))

  a <- data_frame(adm_start_date = start_date, adm_end_date = end_date, ab_start_date = ab_start,
           ab_stop_date = ab_stop, bc_date = bc_date)

return(a)

}
```

This works fine on its own and I want to add those dates to an existing list of patients by id

```
test <- data_frame(id = seq(1,10,1))
```

I tried this approach for `adm_start_date` and `adm_end_date`:

```
test %>% group_by(id) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(adm_start_date = dates()$adm_start_date, adm_end_date = dateR()$adm_end_date)
```

It works for `test[1,]` but throws this error for any n > 1:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: wrong sign in 'by' argument.
```

Someone knows why? Thx a lot!

Comment: Does it work how you want if you remove the `group_by` line?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Comment: What is the `dateR` function from?

Comment: Sorry, typo. It's called dates - from the specified function above

Comment: What is the point of the `group_by`? And why call `dates()` multiple times in a single line - since it returns multiple values wouldn't you want to use the `adm_start_date` and the `adm_end_date` from the same call rather than different calls?

Comment: `mutate` works on rows. Having both `group_by` and `rowwise` as you do is meaningless. Your definition of `dates` requires an argument, yet you are not providing one when you call it in `mutate`.

Comment: I think the `dates` function uses `id` as argument here

Comment: I get a similar the error if I run `dates()$adm_end_date` several (4-10) times in a row: `Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument`.

Comment: Oh, I see.  The date `ab_start` can be after the date `end_date`, so the error happens in `seq` for `ab_stop` whenever that scenario happens.  The function `date` errors out, causing the error message you saw when using it in `mutate`.

Comment: @aosmith Great! That was it. Didn't see this mistake.